# extra space beneath my image links.

Tags: html

I have been working on a simple html landing page and I can't seem to remove the white spacing mid way through the page that my image links are causing. Does anyone have a simple fix for this? Thank you.

Here is a link to the page:
https://www.facebook.com/RevivalCabs/app_190322544333196

Here is my HTML:

```
<body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" topmargin="0" leftmargin="0">
<table id="Table_01" height="792" width="814" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" valign="top">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" colspan="8">
       <img height="369" width="814" border="0" alt="" src="http://i212.photobucket.com    /albums/cc139/takeonecar/Kolossal_MGMT_TOP.jpg">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top">
       <img height="35" width="84" border="0" alt="" src="http://i212.photobucket.com/albums/cc139/takeonecar/Kolossal_MGMT_MID1F.jpg">
    </td>
   <td valign="top">
    <a target="blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/counttofour" >
    <img height="35" width="85" border="0" alt="" src="http://i212.photobucket.com/albums/cc139/takeonecar/Kolossal_MGMT_MID2.jpg">
     </a>
   </td>
   <td valign="top">
    <a target="blank" href="https://twitter.com/CountToFour">
   <img height="35" width="85" border="0" alt="" src="http://i212.photobucket.com/albums/cc139/takeonecar/Kolossal_MGMT_MID3F.jpg">
    </a>
   </td>
   <td valign="top">
    <a target="blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/counttofour">
<img height="35" width="127" border="0" alt="" src="http://i212.photobucket.com/albums/cc139/takeonecar/Kolossal_MGMT_MID4.jpg">
    </a>
   </td>
   <td valign="top">
    <img height="35" width="90" border="0" alt="" src="http://i212.photobucket.com/albums/cc139/takeonecar/Kolossal_MGMT_MID5F.jpg">
   </td>
   <td valign="top">
    <a target="blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/BATTLEGHOST">
<img height="35" width="87" border="0" alt="" src="http://i212.photobucket.com/albums/cc139/takeonecar/Kolossal_MGMT_MID6.jpg">
    </a>
   </td>
   <td valign="top">
    <a target="blank" href="https://twitter.com/BATTLEGHOSTRVA">
     <img height="35" width="86" border="0" alt="" src="http://i212.photobucket.com/albums/cc139/takeonecar/Kolossal_MGMT_MID7.jpg">
    </a>
   </td>
   <td valign="top">
    <a target="blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/counttofour">
     <img height="35" width="170" border="0" alt="" src="http://i212.photobucket.com/albums/cc139/takeonecar/Kolossal_MGMT_MID8.jpg">
    </a>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" colspan="8">
      <div style="height:100%;">
  <img height="388" width="814" border="0" alt="" src="http://i212.photobucket.com/albums/cc139/takeonecar/Kolossal_MGMT_BOTF.jpg"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" colspan="8">
      <img height="12" width="814" border="0" alt="" src="http://i212.photobucket.com/albums/cc139/takeonecar/Kolossal_MGMT_FOOT.jpg">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" colspan="8">
      <img height="12" width="814" border="0" alt="" src="http://i212.photobucket.com/albums/cc139/takeonecar/Kolossal_MGMT_FOOT.jpg">
    </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
 </body>
```

Comment: Just a little tip, don't use tables for layouts.

Comment: `img{display: block;}` should help.